# How to prevent Linux rounding File.lastModified()?

Tags: java, linux, time, rounding, last-modified

I need a high level of precision for getting a file's last modified time. Currently I am using `file.lastModified()` which returns a long value to millisecond precision. e.g. `1443054863000`.

Notice how the last 3 digits are rounded to 000 due to the millisecond limitation. This means that sometimes (not always) when multiple files are modified via a script, even when they are modified one after another, they come out to the same last modified value due to the speed of the script.

Is there any way to get the last modified time more precisely? I do not want to pause my script between file writes. I am limited to Java 1.7

EDIT: This question is not a duplicate. That solution only works for Java 1.8. I specifically said that I am limited to Java 1.7.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the question and its answer are the same: with Java 7, no, you cannot get sub-second resolution. With Java 8, it still relies on a POSIX 2008 compliant host OS.